# why pdo don't save sign of + and & into database?

Tags: php, ajax, pdo

Why when i typed "+-1-23$%^&sdfsdf/><" in the textarea but it save only "-1-23$%^" into database?

Code :

```
function postingMsg (){
        $('.error').hide();
    var messageposting2= $("textarea#messageposting").val();
        var dataString = 'messageposting2='+ messageposting2;
        $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "note-send.php",
             data: dataString,
             success: function(msg) {
         msg = parseFloat(msg)      
             }
        });
        return false;   
}

if ((isset($_POST['messageposting2'])) && (strlen($_POST['messageposting2']) > 0)) {
    $messageposting3 = $_POST['messageposting2'];   

    $sql = "UPDATE users 
            SET my_note=?
            WHERE user_id=?";
    $q = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute(array($messageposting3, $_SESSION['user_id']));

    echo "1";
} else {echo "0";}
```

Comment: What is the value of `$messageposting3`? You mention what you typed, but you didn't mention what the script received.

Comment: of course it is "+-1-23$%^&sdfsdf/><"

Comment: "of course", as in "DUH, that's what it says when I perform an `echo` of the variable" or "I haven't actually printed it, so I'm assuming that's what it has to be, since that's what I typed in"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has nothing to do with PDO or your database. You must URL-encode your string before sending it through Ajax.

```
var dataString = 'messageposting2='+ encodeURIComponent(messageposting2);
```

Comment: WOW. I never knew this thing before. Learn a new thing from u. Thanks.